# Is it possible to add home screens to a Sony Xperia?

Tags: home-screen, launcher, sony-xperia-mini-pro

I've an Xperia Mini/Pro. I would like to add another home screen. At the moment there are 5 different home screen. Is it possible to add more to the Xperia launcher  ?
I don't want to change launcher, i find Xperia stock launcher very ..comfortable with the function 'corners' .
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this might help:
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1138791

you would need to have your phone rooted for this hack. It is for Xperia Play, but would work on other Xperias, as I've done this before on my Xperia Arc S successfully.

Answer (score -1):

Just swap your launcher.
You can use go launcher